# How to set AirPlay device name of the hosting computer?

Tags: airplay

In the AirPlay device list, the name of the hosting computer is always "computer", independently of the computer's actual name.

Is there any way to set this string to a more "expressive" name?

**EDIT**

Setting the host name in the sharing section of the "Systems Preferences" does not work, as the following images demonstrate:

Mac:
[image: host]

iPad:
[image]

Comment: On which device are you looking at the list?

Comment: I've looked from the host itself and from a iPad via the Remote app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did to rename the **Computer** label in the list of available AirPlay speakers in iTunes.

1. In **Finder**, go to your **Applications** folder.
2. Hold the control button and click on the **iTunes** icon. You'll get a pop-up menu.
3. Choose **Show Package Contents** from the pop-up menu. You should now see a **Contents** folder in your Finder window.
4. Use Finder to navigate to the **Contents > Resources >  English.lproj** folder.
5. Open the `Localizable.strings` file in a good text editor.

You may want to make a backup copy of `Localizable.strings` before going any further!

TextEdit isn't good enough. It'll show you gibberish. I used [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html), which is free.

Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for `pb7r8smvm5`. You should see two lines that look like this:

> <key>pb7r8smvm5</key>
>   <string>Computer</string>
>
> Change `Computer` to whatever label you want (e.g., `Living Room`).
>
> Save the `Localizable.strings` file.
>
> Quit **iTunes** and then open it again. Your new label should appear in the list of speakers.
>
> These instructions are for Mac OS X. [Windows instructions are available](https://www.avforums.com/threads/renaming-airtunes-my-computer-label.1224980/).

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Systems Preferences -> Sharing` and edit your computer name.

[image]

From your iOS device, this name will display when you use AirPlay:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a setting of the name in sharing does not work, see edit.

Comment: Odd. I change it in mine, and it changes to the new name. I tried it on another Mac on my network, and it works on there as well.